# How to Make Spring form as Read Only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp

In my Application i'm using Spring Supplied tags...

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

    <fieldset id="user1">
       <form:form action="frm1" modelAttribute="SUPER" >
         ------
         ------
       </form:form>
    </fieldset>
```

And My Requirement is basically Form is only Read only when we click Edit button of the form then only form will change Editable mode.

I'm trying `readonly` Property but not work .. i think this property for html.

Please give me suggestion how to do this in any java related technology..
Like javascript and JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **c tag library** to assign the values to your inputs from your model while using readonly="readonly" property.

```
<form:form id="simpleDomainForm" modelAttribute="simpleDomain">
<input name="modelId" value='<c:out value="${simpleDomain.modelId}"></c:out>' readonly="readonly" class="required">
<input name="modelName" value='<c:out value="${simpleDomain.modelName}"></c:out>' readonly="readonly" class="required">
<input type="button" value="Toggle" onclick="toggleForm();">
</form:form>
```

And jQuery you can enable these input boxes on click event of **Edit** button. Following is a simple example of script using jQuery to toggle readonly state of inputs.

[*Note: This is just a simple example, you need to customize it according to your requirement*]

```
<script>
function toggleForm(){
    if($("#simpleDomainForm").children(".required").attr("readonly") == "readonly")
        $("#simpleDomainForm").children(".required").removeAttr("readonly");
    else
        $("#simpleDomainForm").children(".required").attr("readonly", "readonly");
}
</script>
```

Comment: ok.. this is fine when we click edit button again we want to write some lines of code but is their any option for using form id can add readonly option and when we click Edit button this property change to readonly false...

Comment: To change dom attributes check attr(http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and if you want to remove some attributes you can use removeAttr(http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function of jQuery

Answer (score 16):

The type of `readonly` property is Boolean, so it should be `readonly="true"`:

```
<form:input path="firstName" class="form-control"
            placeholder="First Name"  type="text" readonly="true"/>
```